# @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) is disallowed for this location

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I am getting following error

`The annotation @RunWith is disallowed for this   location`

I have following imports.

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(QueryValidator.class)
@Test
public void testValidateIds2() { ... }
```

What is causing this and how can I get rid of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` is a class level annotation and needs to go on top of the class, not the method.